# Counting occurrences of a word in a text file without count function

Tags: python, windows

I am learning Python, and I'm supposed to create a program that takes a user's input for a single word and then returns the number of times that word occurs in the text file. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to go about this, been wracking for hours watching videos and such. I can't use the `.count() function.

Here is my code:

```py
import string
frank = open('Frankenstein.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
frank_poem = frank.read()

frank_poem = frank_poem.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))

split_poem = frank_poem.split()

word = input("Please enter the word you would like to count in Frankenstein (case-sensitive): ")

def word_count(word):
    total = 0
    for word in split_poem:
        total += word
    return total

print(word_count(word))
```

Comment: In your loop, you're overwriting the original `word` variable. Change it to, e.g., `for w in split_poem:`, then you can check if `w` is equal to `word`, and add 1 to `total` if so.

Comment: that's the answer, thanks a ton friend

Comment: The match is case-sensitive so any case differences won't add to the count (e.g. "Monster" != "monster"). If you want case insensitive matches then should convert words to same case when comparing.

Comment: duly noted, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
total += word
```

is adding a string, `word`, to `total`. You probably are looking for `total += 1`, rather than `total += word`. You'll then need to add an `if` statement to check if the word you're currently examining is equivalent to the target word, like so:

```py
def word_count(target_word):
    total = 0
    for word in split_poem:
        if word == target_word:
            total += 1
    return total
```

Comment: The problem then is I'm not calling 'word' in the for function

Comment: Edited, there's one more thing you need to do to fix the issue.

Comment: somebody else helped me with this, you have the correct answer. Thanks! I will accept the answer when It lets me

Comment: No problem. Have a great evening, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```
def word_count(word):
    total = 0
    for poem_word in split_poem:
        if word == poem_word:
                total += 1
    return total

print(word_count(word))
```

Here is an alternative that is more concise but does not use `count`. It relies on the fact that a `boolean` value of `True` (such as when `poem_word == word` is `True`) gets converted to an integer value of `1` for the built-in function `sum()`.

```
def word_count(word):
    return sum(poem_word == word for poem_word in split_poem)
```

Comment: that's very clever, and helpful for a learner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
frank = open('Frankenstein.txt','r',encoding='utf-8')
frank_poem = frank.read()

frank_poem = frank_poem.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))

split_poem = frank_poem.split()

word = input("Please enter the word you would like to count: ")

def word_count():
    total = 0
    for wordi in split_poem:
        if wordi == word:
            total += 1
    return total

print(word_count())
```